# NodeJs embedding richtext(html) in docx built using "docx" package

Tags: node.js, docx, html-to-docx

I have written my creating of docx file using the "docx" nodejs package, and I got a new requirement to add rich text content into my docx, somewhere in the middle of the file (formatted as it looks in rich text of course).

All I found was packages that takes full html and creates a brand new docx, but I want to take the html and embed it in the existing docx (I don't care saving the docx and then manipulating it afterwards).

All I find requires me to fully change my docx creation to another package, but I can't find adding it to an existing file.

Thanks in Advance !

I tried:

- docxtemplater package,
  but it required changing all of the docx creation process.
- docx-templates package, but its also only works for creating a new document.
  when trying to use the +++HTML, when creating the docx, and then running the package on the complete docx, I got a corrupted docx (which was valid before running the package on it).
- I also tried parsing it all by myself, but I had so many niches that it made a few hours feature, to a full sprint feature (with a great possibility for bugs)

I expect to build the docx step by step using the docx package, and when I get to the richtext, transform it to something that docx supports (and still holds the rich medatada like color, size and everything).